# Apply function to find elements not in a list

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I want to apply a function that returns the elements not found in a reference list. What I want to get is the following.

```
import pandas as pd

product_list = ['Chive & Garlic', 'The Big Smoke',
                'Jalapeno & Lemon', 'Spinach & Artichoke']

data = [['ACTIVE BODY', ['Chive & Garlic', 'The Big Smoke'], ['Jalapeno & Lemon', 'Spinach & Artichoke']],
        ['AG VALLEY FOODS', ['Chive & Garlic', 'Spinach & Artichoke'], ['The Big Smoke', 'Jalapeno & Lemon']],
        ['ALIM MICHEL HALLORAN', ['The Big Smoke', 'Chive & Garlic'], ['Jalapeno & Lemon', 'Spinach & Artichoke']],
        ['ALIMENTATION IAN DES', ['The Big Smoke', 'Jalapeno & Lemon'],['Chive & Garlic', 'Spinach & Artichoke']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['store', 'products', 'missing_products'])
```

[image]

where `missing_products` are the products in list type, not found in the array of the `products` column

I tried the following function but it's not working as intended

```
def gap(row):
    for item in product_list:
        if item not in row:
            return item
```

Important to note that each value in the `products` column is an array, not list of strings. Not sure if this affects something.

```
[['ACADEMIE DU GOURMET ACADEMY INC', array([nan], dtype=object)],
 ['ACTIVE BODY',
  array(['Chive & Garlic', 'Garlic Tzatziki', 'The Big Smoke'], dtype=object)],
 ['AG VALLEY FOODS',
  array(['Chive & Garlic', 'Spinach & Artichoke'], dtype=object)],
 ['ALIM MICHEL HALLORAN',
  array(['The Meadow', 'The Big Smoke', 'Chive & Garlic',
         'Jalapeno & Lemon', 'Dill & Truffle'], dtype=object)],
 ['ALIMENTATION IAN DES',
  array(['The Big Smoke', 'Jalapeno & Lemon'], dtype=object)]]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can't you use `list()` or `set()` to parse it to list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use `set` operations, this should be the most efficient:

```
S = set(product_list)

df['missing_products'] = [list(S.difference(x)) for x in df['products']]
```

Output:

```
                  store                               products  \
0           ACTIVE BODY        [Chive & Garlic, The Big Smoke]   
1       AG VALLEY FOODS  [Chive & Garlic, Spinach & Artichoke]   
2  ALIM MICHEL HALLORAN        [The Big Smoke, Chive & Garlic]   
3  ALIMENTATION IAN DES      [The Big Smoke, Jalapeno & Lemon]   

                          missing_products  
0  [Spinach & Artichoke, Jalapeno & Lemon]  
1        [Jalapeno & Lemon, The Big Smoke]  
2  [Spinach & Artichoke, Jalapeno & Lemon]  
3    [Spinach & Artichoke, Chive & Garlic]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create helper list and append matched values:

```
def gap(row):
    out = []
    for item in product_list:
        if item not in row:
            out.append(item)
    return out
```

Alternative with list comprehension:

```
def gap(row):
    return [item for item in product_list if item not in row]


df['missing_products1'] = df['products'].apply(gap)
```

List comprehension only solution:

```
df['missing_products1'] = [[item for item in product_list if item not in row] for row in df['products']]
```

Comment: I will write the alternative way(one-liner). I edited your post :). Nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the data frame as a binary data frame where if the store has the product you put `1`, and if not you put `0`.

That way it can be more generic instead of just lists in the data frame.